# App doesn't run correctly from ToastNotification action

Tags: notifications, win-universal-app, toast, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to make a very simple demo to show how to work with Background Tasks and Toast Notifications in **UWP**. I've a simple task, which is triggered on network connection change and his work is to show a simple notification. It's of course registered in OS, selected in manifest and this task works well.

I've created a package and installed the app in my laptop to try if it run even in the moment when the app isn't launched. Task works as well.

The only problem is, that when I click on "Run app" button in notification, I want to launch app running in foreground. It starts app, but the only thing I can see is splash screen of my app and nothing else happened. I saw [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts) tutorial to this notification and my XML is almost the same.

My XML notification's content:

```
<toast launch="app-defined-string">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Test notification</text>
      <text>This is a simple toast notification</text>
      <image placement="AppLogoOverride" src="../Assets/icon.png"/>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
    <action activationType="foreground" content="Run App" arguments="check" />
  </actions>
  <audio src="ms-winsoundevent:Notification.SMS" />
</toast>
```

**UPDATE**

The only modified part in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
  {
    var toastArgs = (ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)args;
    ToastArg = toastArgs.Argument;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your App.xaml.cs ?

Comment: Of course, I've added the only modified part of App.xaml.cs, rest of it is just standard "starting" Application code. But I tried it without this code and the result was same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the initialization of your app (things inside OnLaunch method) from OnActivated. Remember to check if your app is running or not when initialization.

Comment: Thanks for great hint, I really don't have no idea that OnLaunched method doesn't fire when you lauch app from notification. The main missing information was probably: `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), arg);`